# reactive subset involving is.na function don't work in Shiny (R)

Tags: r, shiny, subset

I try to build a Shiny App in order to display scatter plot from reactive subset. Actually, the app works, I have everything that I want, **however it seems that my subsetting function cannot do the job**. Meanning that my plots display points which are NA for my input$vlabel variable.

Here is my `base` dataset

```
x=rnorm(100,1 , 5)
y=rnorm(100, 5, 1)
z=rnorm(100, 3, 7)
lab_a=ifelse(as.logical(rbinom(100,1,1/6)),TRUE,NA)
lab_b=ifelse(as.logical(rbinom(100,1,1/5)),TRUE,NA)
base=as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,z,lab_a,lab_b))
names(base)=c("variable1","variable2","variable3","lab_a","lab_b")
```

Here is my server.R :

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)

#load data
my_data=base

# Define server logic required to plot variables
shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  #subset data
  newdata<- reactive({
    subset(my_data,is.na(input$vlabel)==FALSE)
  })

  # Create a reactive text
  text <- reactive({
    paste(input$variable, 'versus', input$variable2)
  })

  # Return as text the selected variables
  output$caption <- renderText({
    text()
  })

  # Generate a plot of the requested variables
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    p <- ggplot(newdata(), aes_string(x=input$variable, y=input$variable2, colour=input$vlabel)) + geom_point()
    print(p)
  })


})
```

Here is my ui.R :

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for iris application
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  # Application title
  headerPanel("Seasonnality"),

  # Sidebar with controls to select the variable to plot against mpg
  # and to specify whether outliers should be included
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("vlabel", "Label variable:",
                list("Label A" = "lab_a",
                     "Label B"  = "lab_b")),

    selectInput("variable", "First variable:",
                list("Variable 1" = "variable1",
                     "Variable 2"  = "variable2",
                     "Variable 3" = "variable3")),

    selectInput("variable2", "Second variable:",
                list("Variable 1" = "variable1",
                     "Variable 2"  = "variable2",
                     "Variable 3" = "variable3"))
  ),

  mainPanel(
    h3(textOutput("caption")),
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
))
```

As you can see, every points are displayed on my plot whereas I want to plot only point which are not NA for my `input$vlabel` variable. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I don't know exactly why the previous version of my code don't work,
but this way, it's fine :

```
  newdata<- reactive({
    my_data=my_data[is.na(my_data[input$vlabel])==FALSE,]
    my_data
  })
```